# Stata Store Slope

Tags: stata, store, mixed-models, mixed

```
STUDENT TIME    SCORE
1   1   9
1   2   11
1   3   7
2   1   8
2   2   6
2   3   14
2   4   11
3   1   14
3   2   10
3   3   9
4   1   14
4   2   6

mixed SCORE || STUDENT:TIME
```

I wish to estimate SLOPES and INTERCEPTS for each STUDENT to attain a data set such as

```
STUDENT TIME    SCORE   RANDOMSLOPE RANDOMINTERCEPT
1   1   9       
1   2   11      
1   3   7       
2   1   8       
2   2   6       
2   3   14      
2   4   11      
3   1   14      
3   2   10      
3   3   9       
4   1   14      
4   2   6
```

However I am insure of how to store the intercept and slope for every STUDENT

Comment: are you looking for something like `predict re*, reffects`?

Comment: @langtang YES, TY So much. It gives me re1 and re2, is one the intercept and one slope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference here may be helpful,  for random slope in Chapter 4 (https://errickson.net/stata-mixed/random-slopes.html) and for predicting random in Chapter 3.3 (https://errickson.net/stata-mixed/fitting-linear-mixed-models.html). The reference uses "predict rintercept, reffects" to get the random intercepts.
Also, the postestimation part of the Stata manual (https://www.stata.com/manuals/me.pdf) page 543 - page 546 is relevant for you to figure out the definition of re1 and re2.